# How to use sed/awk/grep

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a text given below...

```
tcpmux  1/tcp   0.001995    # TCP Port Service Multiplexer [rfc-1078] 
tcpmux  1/udp   0.001236    # TCP Port Service Multiplexer
compressnet 2/tcp   0.000013    # Management Utility
compressnet 3/tcp   0.001242    # Compression Process
unknown 10/tcp  0.000063
```

Here i dont want string ***0.00***... from all lines

### How to remove ***0.00..*** values from text

(i.e) my output wants to be

```
tcpmux  1/tcp      #TCP Port Service Multiplexer [rfc-1078] 
tcpmux  1/udp      #TCP Port Service Multiplexer
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried, and the results?

Comment: Quick and dirty: `awk '{$3=""}1' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don't need `grep` in order to get the output that you want. You can filter text using `sed`.

Supposing that your text is saved in `text.txt`, you can use `sed` like this:

```
sed  's/0\.00[0-9]*//' text.txt
```

Comment: You need not to use `cat` with `sed` as it could read file itself.

Comment: `.` is special in a regex.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene 
I just add a escape character for `.`

Comment: @cristianpb Here are some examples of the useless use of cat and related things. People here will always complain about these. http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Thanks @NiallCosgrove

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk '/^tcpmux/{sub(/0.00..../,"    "); print $0}' file

tcpmux 1/tcp      # TCP Port Service Multiplexer [rfc-1078]
tcpmux 1/udp      # TCP Port Service Multiplexer
```